# Django / DRF - Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `users_answers_set` on serializer `TestTakerSerializer`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

everyone. I want to make a test in DRF. But DRF gave me this error:

models.py:

```
class TestTaker(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UsersAnswers(models.Model):
    test_taker = models.ForeignKey(TestTaker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class UsersAnswersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UsersAnswers
        fields = "__all__"
   
class TestTakerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users_answers_set = UsersAnswersSerializer(many=True)
class Meta:
        model = TestTaker
        fields = "__all__"
```

And the error is:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `users_answers_set` on serializer `TestTakerSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `TestTaker` instance.
Original exception text was: 'TestTaker' object has no attribute 'users_answers_set'.
```

I tried to add "source" parameter to users_answers_set, but nothing changed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `usersanswers_set` instead of `users_answers_set`.

or

you can define custom related_name in your model:

```
class UsersAnswers(models.Model):
    test_taker = models.ForeignKey(TestTaker, related_name="users_answers_set" , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```